# Parameter map not working in list view local data source in kendo ui

Tags: kendo-ui

I am using two datasources in the list view. The first one is list view datasource and the second one is local datasource. I am adding multiple items to the local datasource. On save click i want to save all the values in the local datasource to the database.

In the button click i am using localdatasource.sync() method to call the create method.
But it is not entering in to the parameter map.

Simply In my database i am having 10 list view items. Initially i am loading 1 item and on next button click i am loading next item. Then when i am saving the question on next button click to the local datasource. On complete button click i want to save all the values.

Regards,

Sri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to create a dataSource which is configured for remote operations and you populate it initially through the **[data](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#data-array)** field of the dataSource configurator?
Something like this:

```
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: {
                "url": "/Home/GetPersons"
            },
            update: {
                "url": "/Home/UpdatePerson"
            }
        },
        data: {
            Data: [{
                PersonID: 1,
                Name: "John",
                BirthDate: "\/Date(-47876400000)\/"},
            {
                PersonID: 2,
                Name: "Sara",
                BirthDate: "\/Date(148251600000)\/"}],
            Total: 2
        }
        //... etc. other options 
    }
```